# why my function params said to be undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function orangeCost(oneOrange){
    //this.OneOrange = oneOrange;
    var total = OneOrange *  OneOrange;
    console.log(total);
}

orangeCost(5);
```

I was expecting 5 to be pass in the param and within the function it can be use like variable, not working untill I use the `this` keyword (line 2), why?

Comment: `OneOrange` is not the same as  `oneOrange` (note the first character). The reason why it works with `this.OneOrange = oneOrange;` is that this statement creates a global variable `OneOrange` with the value of `oneOrange`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo, which is not going to be of much use to anyone else.

Comment: pls don't vote down, my bad LULZZZ

Comment: If you spend more time debugging, you'll not need to worry about getting voted down. First place you should look is your developer console. It would give you a ReferenceError for attempting to read the undeclared variable.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript is case sensitive.

`o` is small here -> `function orangeCost(oneOrange){`

Change

```
var total = OneOrange *  OneOrange;
```

to

```
var total = oneOrange *  oneOrange;
```

OR

change

```
function orangeCost(oneOrange){
```

to

```
function orangeCost(OneOrange){
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't made any copy-paste typos, you have oneOrange parameter, holding 5, and OneOrange local variable, which is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript everytihng is case sensitive which means that variables, function names, and operators are all case sensitive.

So, variable `oneOrange` is different from `OneOrange`. That is reason you got the message about undefined variable. And your function input parameter is defined but variable 'OneOrange' is not.

You have to change line

```
var total = OneOrange *  OneOrange;
```

to

```
var total = oneOrange *  oneOrange;
```

And better not use variables like `OneOrange` because by convention they are used for constructors.